# how to add roster with subcription both to someone jid?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

i hav a social site that for its chat i decide to use XMPP.so i install ejabberd as an XMPP Serve and use Jaxl lib for php to handle ejabberd.
for client also i use Strophe to send and recieve stanzas.
My problem is that i already have a list of friends that there is no exist on ejabberd server so i want to add item to roster of some one jid from server with subscription Both without any subscription suggestion to that jid.how can i do it?
I dont want use ejabberdctl so adhoc and xmlrpc and mod_* that use command execution is not suitable,i wanna Do it with just stanza.
Is there any way to do it with admin account(jid)?

Comment: i try to do this:<ejabberdctl add_roster> with subscription "both" by stanzas not by command

Answer (score 1):

You can bind ejabberd with mysql and use `mod_roster_odbc` ,So all of your roster item stores in `rosterusers` table.

you can directly insert your roster items in this table.

Comment: do the clients get any update in real time when you add/delete rosters directly on the database?

Answer (score -1):

> I dont want use ejabberdctl so adhoc and xmlrpc and mod_* that use command execution is not suitable,i wanna Do it with just stanza.

If you don't want to use the available interfaces, you will need to write a custom module for do that with custom stanzas as you want.